Как реализовать SharpNEAT в Unity с возможностью добавления повторяющихся соединений?
Как реализовать алгоритм NEAT для нейронных сетей в Unity с возможностью добавления рекуррентных соединений? У нас есть множество реализаций SharpNEAT в Unity, вот некоторые из них: GitHub - lordjesus/UnityNEAT: Порт SharpNEAT для Unity 4.x и 5.x, GitHub - flo-wolf/UnitySharpNEAT: Реализация SharpNEAT в Unity 2020. Полный рефакторинг проекта UnityNEAT. (новее). Однако они не поддерживают рекуррентные соединения, как их добавить?
